Linkedin automation connection bot with people from search
I do have a side project which i found very challenging and at the same time very interesting.
So! Idea is very simple!
Using Selenium!
Log in to Linkedln!
Go to search link with your parameters - in my case it's tech. recruiters.
Every page has 10 buttons. State of the button is "Connect", "Follow" or "Message"
The goal is every time I check the button, if it's "Connect" or "Follow" we want to click it.
If it's "Connect" also add a custom message.
When we done with 10 buttons --> go to next page --> Repeat --> Grow your Linkedin!
That was my plan till I started facing problems.
I do have functionality working for "Go to next page" --> we have to scroll to the bottom and click "Next page".
I do have functionality working for "Connect" button when it was clicked, so I can add a custom note and send invitation to connect.
The problem I'm facing that when bot working, it's skipping "Connect" and "Follow" buttons - I will attach code for this part.
Full code will be on github - full code
def process_buttons(driver, base_message, max_requests):
    requests_sent = 0
    buttons_processed = 0

    while buttons_processed < 10:
        try:
            buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'entity-result__actions')]/div/button")
            if not buttons:
                logging.info("No buttons found on this page.")
                break

            for button in buttons:
                if requests_sent >= max_requests:
                    break

                # Check the text content of the button
                try:
                    button_text = button.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'span').text.strip()
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    logging.info("No span element found in the button, skipping.")
                    continue

                logging.info(f"Button text: {button_text}")

                try:
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)
                    time.sleep(1)  # Ensure the element is in view
                except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
                    logging.info(f"Move target out of bounds for button with text: {button_text}")
                    continue

                if button_text.lower() == "connect":
                    try:
                        logging.info(f"Found Connect button with text: {button_text}")
                        send_connection_request(driver, button, base_message)
                        requests_sent += 1
                        print(requests_sent)
                        time.sleep(5)  # Sleep for 5 seconds after sending each connection request
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.info(f"Skipping already connected or unavailable user: {e}")
                        continue
                elif button_text.lower() == "follow":
                    try:
                        logging.info(f"Found Follow button with text: {button_text}")
                        button.click()
                        logging.info(f"Followed user with text: {button_text}")
                        print(requests_sent)
                        time.sleep(5)  # Sleep for 5 seconds after following each user
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.info(f"Error following user: {e}")
                        continue
                elif button_text.lower() == "message":
                    logging.info(f"Skipping user with Message button: {button_text}")
                    continue  # Skip users with the Message button

                buttons_processed += 1
                if buttons_processed >= 10:
                    break

        except TimeoutException:
            logging.error(f"Timeout while processing buttons.")
            break

        if not go_to_next_page(driver):
            break

def send_connection_requests(driver, search_link, max_requests, base_message):
    driver.get(search_link)

    while True:
        process_buttons(driver, base_message, max_requests)
        if not go_to_next_page(driver):
            break

I also tried working only with XPATHs. For example, we know that we only have to check 10 buttons, I tried getting those 10 XPATH and checking with each button if it mathes. Did not work.

what do you mean "it skips"? you're sure there are only those three types of buttons?

@folengateis, yes, check it your self when you are searching. "Connect", "Follow" and "Message". Skips? - dont click on the button when the button is available.

never publish your password! change your linkedin password and hide login info from your github script

unless you provide some html sample ([mre]), it's hard to tell what is the problem here. your code looks ok so: maybe your xpath doesn't catch all the buttons you want, maybe button_text.lower() does a bad job at filtering

@folengateis, thank you! I was so focused on the problem, that I pushed a log-in info)

@folengateis, I'm not sure if you can. But if you do run the code as it is, it will live demo. The driver is included in a repo. I tried several approaches)
